# Telegram bot: How to mention user by its id (not its username)

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am creating a telegram bot and using `sendMessage` method to send the messages.
it is easy to mention user using `@username`, But how to mention user when they don't have username?

If using the telegram app/web, we can mentioned the user by `@integer_id (name)`, and telegram app/web will convert it into clickable text. `integer_id` will be generated automatically when we select the user, after typing `@`.

another background:
I am trying to use [`forceReply`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply) and I want to target user, if they have username, I can easily target them, by mentioning them on the text on `sendMessage` method.

the bot I am creating is a "quiz" like bot. where each player need to take turn, and the bot is sending them the question, each msg from bot will target different player.

NOTE: I am not disabling the `Privacy Mode`, I don't want telegram bombing my server with msg I don't need. it was overloading my cheap nasty server. so, disabling it not an option.

I am open for other solution, where the bot can listen to selected player.

thanks.

UPDATE 21/10:
I've spoke to BotSupport for telegram, they said, for now Bots can't mention user without username.

so in my case, I still keep using `forceReply`, and also, gave a short msg to user which doesn't have username to set it up, so they can get the benefit from `forceReply` function.

Answer (score 57):

According to [official documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style) it is possible to mention user by its numerical id with markup:

`[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)`

Comment: These mentions are only guaranteed to work if the user has contacted the bot in the past, has sent a callback query to the bot via inline button or is a member in the group where he was mentioned.

Comment: Another problem with this method is that it will notify the user, even if you set `disable_notification`.

Comment: Not working if the user disables "Forwarded Messages" from privacy setting

Answer (score 28):

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905948/) :
it is possible to mention user by its numerical id with markup:

> **Markdown style**
>
> To use this mode, pass Markdown in the `parse_mode` field
>   when using `sendMessage`. Use the following syntax in your message:

```
[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)
```

and you can also use `HTML` style :

> **HTML style**
>
> To use this mode, pass HTML in the parse_mode field when using sendMessage. The following tags are currently supported:

```
<a href="tg://user?id=123456789">inline mention of a user</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)     
def echo_message(message):
    cid = message.chat.id 
    message_text = message.text 
    user_id = message.from_user.id 
    user_name = message.from_user.first_name 
    mention = "["+user_name+"](tg://user?id="+str(user_id)+")"
    bot_msg = f"Hi, {mention}"
    if message_text.lower() == "hi":
        bot.send_message(cid, bot_msg, parse_mode="Markdown")
```

Answer (score 2):

For `python-telegram-bot` you can do the following:

```
user_id = update.message.from_user['id']
user_name = update.message.from_user['username']

mention = "["+user_name+"](tg://user?id="+str(user_id)+")"
response = f"Hi, {mention}"

context.bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,text=response,parse_mode="Markdown")
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this restriction is related to Telegram's privacy policy and prevention of abuse.

It is possible to mention a user when sending messages (BOT API), but that is not what you need:

`[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=<user_id>)`

```
Links tg://user?id= can be used to mention a user by their id without using a username. Please note:

These links will work only if they are used inside an inline link. For example, they will not work, when used in an inline keyboard button or in a message text.
These mentions are only guaranteed to work if the user has contacted the bot in the past, has sent a callback query to the bot via inline button or is a member in the group where he was mentioned.
```

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style

Answer (score 1):

you need to link to the text: "tg://user?id=" and id

```
user_id = 123456XX # id of the user to mention
chat_id = 123456XXX # chat id where to mention
user_name = name of user
await bot.send_message(chat_id, f"<a href='tg://user?id={user_id}'>{user_name}</a>", "HTML")
```

here is an example:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def mention(msg: types.Message):
    await msg.answer(f"<a href='tg://user?id={msg.from_user.id}'>{msg.from_user.full_name}</a>", "HTML")
```

Answer (score -4):

Bots are able to tag users by their ID, they just can't do this using the official HTTP Bot API.

Update: Not necessairy anymore, since Telegram added native Support for this.

If you log into your bots account with [MadelineProto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto) (PHP) you can use this 'link' to mention someone by it's ID with parse_mode set to markdown

```
[Daniil Gentili](mention:@danogentili)
```

Comment: OP wants to know how to mention users by their user ID and It's a 32bit integer, not by username that you suggested

Comment: @Reith Have a look at the MadelineProto Documentation. You could hust replace the @username with a number. E.g. `[Daniil Gentili](mention:123456789)`

Comment: MadelineProto uses MTProto, not a Telegram Bot API