# How can I mention Telegram users without a username?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I want mention users even those which d*o not have a username*.

If a user has set up a username I return

```
Hi @username
```

as an answer but if a user does not have one I can't do that.

I tried using the unique User ID e.g.

```
@5642166
```

but that did not work.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

According to [official documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style) it is possible to mention user by its numerical id with markup:

> **Markdown style**
>
> To use this mode, pass Markdown in the `parse_mode` field
>   when using `sendMessage`. Use the following syntax in your message:

```
[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)
```

and you can also use `HTML` style :

> **HTML style**
>
> To use this mode, pass HTML in the parse_mode field when using sendMessage. The following tags are currently supported:

```
<a href="tg://user?id=123456789">inline mention of a user</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example below should work.

```
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
                         parse_mode = ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2, 
                         text = "[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)")
```