# How do you mention a user in Telegram who has no "@" or username?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

The question seems to have been answered here [How can I mention Telegram users without a username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905948/how-can-i-mention-telegram-users-without-a-username), but I don't know how to write it using PTB.

The documentation link to the documentation (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style) also doesn't help me since I'm too much of a novice to understand it and don't know what inline or markdown is. So how should I write the code below for it to work?

```
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=-1111111111, text="hi")
```

Comment: What do you mean, "I don't know how to do it specifically"? The question you linked *tells you* specifically how to do it.

Comment: I mean how to write the code specifically. The documentation isn't clear to me or gives examples. If it is clear to you then fine but to me its not because I am a novice.