# I need example on how to mention using PTB

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I need further elaboration on this thread [How can I mention Telegram users without a username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905948/how-can-i-mention-telegram-users-without-a-username)

Can someone give me an example of how to use the markdown style? I am also using PTB library

The code I want modified

```
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=-1111111111, text="hi")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I finally found the answer. The example below should work.

```
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
                         parse_mode = ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2, 
                         text = "[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)")
```